# Do you absolutely need a basis type "bs=" in a GAM model?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, predictor

Under what circumstances would you NOT NEED to assign a basis (ex. basis="cr") type in a GAM model? For a simple model, to see what the effect of one environmental variable is on abundance, would one not need a basis to assign a smooth? I am assigning a K value.

```
  Ex.     
  View1 <- gam(abundanceA~ s(Path, bs="cr", k=30),
                data=dat,   
                 method="REML")
```

Comment: jbowman's answer kinda covers this, but just to be very clear there's always a `bs` when you call `s()` because Simon Wood made the TPRS basis the default and set a default value of `"tp"` for the `bs` argument to `s()`: see `args(mgcv::s)`. As such, even if you don't explicitly pass something to this argument you are assigning something to the argument. What is the motivation behind your question? Surely you tried it without setting `bs` and saw that it worked? So I'm wondering if there's something more that motivated the question?

Comment: Thank you, @GavinSimpson-- Yes, it worked without setting bs. I had two outcomes where a basis="cr" was used and there was more wiggle in the effect than expected. Without it there was less wiggle as expected for a variable that does not have a lot of variability. I also wonder how different predicted data will be with and without a basis type, highly contextual depending on the covariate I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default basis for `gam` in the `mgcv` package is a thin-plate spline (`bs="tp"`), so you don't need to assign one if that's what you want.  You also don't need to assign one if you aren't going to smooth the variable, in which case you don't want to use the `s` notation either; the same notation used in `lm` or `glm` works:

`gam(y ~ x1 + s(x2) + s(x3, bs="cr", k=5))`

Answer (score 1):

In **mgcv** penalized regression is used to fit models. Penalized regression requires a basis set of functions by its nature. If you don't set a basis, `gam` uses thin plate splines, which as said in [Wood (2017)](https://www.routledge.com/Generalized-Additive-Models-An-Introduction-with-R-Second-Edition/Wood/p/book/9781498728331) is a powerful and reasonable default.

Not all smoothers are based on penalized regression and does not require a basis as a result. [Hastie and Tibshirani (1990)](https://www.routledge.com/Generalized-Additive-Models/Hastie-Tibshirani/p/book/9780412343902) included other types of smoothers in their framework, such as moving average/LOESS-type smoothers, which can be fit using their backfitting algorithm and is provided in the R package **gam**.

When thinking about smoothers to use, you should be thinking about what properties you want the smooth to have, such as differentiability or working well with multiple inputs, but those issues aside, the smoother itself (basis set, LOESS, etc.) probably shouldn't matter too much, and issues such as ability to compute quickly or properties such as differentiability should drive the decision more. The bigger concern is always parameters controlling the level of smoothing. All smoothers have something that controls how smooth it is (the level of penalization, or the bandwidth for moving averages), and that has greater influence on fit quality.